# Is it possible to spend the unspent outputs of a burn address?

Tags: transactions, utxo, non-standard-transaction

If a burn address is created without a private key to prevent access to the bitcoin there, is not possible to create a transaction which would spend the utxos since there is no private key to sign the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

> not possible to create a transaction which would spend the utxos since there is no private key to sign the transaction?

Yes. That's the whole point of a burn address - to have an address where no one is able to spend the coins.

Of course, in theory, someone could find a private key that corresponds to a burn address, but the probability is so small that it is effectively 0.